# Reverse Proxy lighttpd https not working

Tags: tomcat, https, proxy, lighttpd, forwarding

I have multiple Tomcats running on my Server. I use lighttpd to reverse proxy the incoming requests for different domains. So far I only used http without https and this config worked for me:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "my.domain.com" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => ( (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 8080
    ) ) )
}
```

But when I try the same and only change the port to the https port I only see a blank page. What do I need to do to redirect traffic to the Tomcat that uses https.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$SERVER["socket"]` rather than `$HTTP["host"]` e.g.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "my.domain.com:443" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => ( (
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => 8080
    ) ) )
}
```